# Excel diagram type for x-y-value datas

Tags: excel, diagram

To visual my calculation values I create debug csv-files with following structure:

```
x;y;value
```

I can open this file in Excel (2019) without any problem. To check my values I try to add a diagram which shows the 3D-points. But I found no diagram type in Excel. Excel always creates diagrams with two bars: x;value and y;value.

Is there a simple way with Excel or another alternative?

Thanks in advance for your recommendations!

Comment: This question would be better suited to https://superuser.com/ . That said, it might be a good idea to provide a sample chart showing the result you are expecting

Comment: Would a bubble chart help you visualize your data better?

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomad. I followed your suggestion and create a more detailed question on https://superuser.com/questions/1439987/excel-diagram-type-for-x-y-value-datas-or-better-tooling